# Create if statement using integer

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I am pretty new to xcode so forgive my mistakes but I am trying to convert a string into an integer and then create an if statement that makes a button disabled if the value if the integer is less than 15. The integer is stored in a string  and I know works correctly because I can display it in a label. I am having trouble converting that string into an integer and then making the button disabled if the score is less than 15. I have no errors, but the code is not working. Here is what I have so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"levelScore"];


    int level = [savedValue intValue];



    if (level <= 15) {
       levelTwo.enabled = NO;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having? Is it erroring out, just not working? A bit more description would be very helpful. (Mostly because this code looks fine)

Comment: Im sorry I didn't include that. Yes the code is just not working, I have no errors.

Comment: Looks like @madhu has a solution that you might want to try, but for future reference, if you're having non-fatal issues, add breakpoints (click the line number in Xcode) and verify the values of the various variables.

Comment: I didn't know what breakpoints are for, thanks for that though, I will defiantly look into that.

Comment: Breakpoints interrupt your code and let you poke around and see what's happening (via the Gnu Debugger [GDB] in Xcode).

Comment: Could you recommend a good breakpoints tutorial online. I couldn't find a good one for Xcode 4. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {


        NSString *savedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                stringForKey:@"levelScore"]];

         or

        NSString *savedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"levelScore"]];



        int level = [savedValue intValue];



        if (level <= 15) {
            levelTwo.enabled = NO;
        }
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! But is there a way to display a text box instead of the button and hide the button all together?

Comment: if (level <= 15) {
            urtextfiled.text = level; levelTwo.enabled = NO;levelTwo.hidden=YES;
        }

Comment: Absolutely. It might take a bit of UIView swapping magic though.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"levelScore"] <= 15)
       levelTwo.enabled = NO;
}
```